# Grep only for lowercase and spaces

Tags: regex, bash, grep, gnu

I need to grep files for lines containing only lowercase letters and spaces. Both conditions must be met at least once and no other characters are allowed.

I know how to grep only for lowercase or only for space but I don't know how to join those two conditions in one regexp/command.

I have only this right now:

```
egrep "[[:space:]]" $DIR/$file | egrep -vq "[[:upper:]]"
```

which of course will display lines with digits and/or special characters as well which is not what I want.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you require

The `-x` matches whole lines

The first expression matches lines composed entirely of spaces and lower case letters.

The second expression matches lines that have both a space and a lower case letter.

`egrep -x '[[:lower:] ]*'  $DIR/$file | egrep '( [[:lower:]])|([[:lower:]] )'`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not because when I test it it outputs lines without space as well. To be more specific - the whitespaces can be positioned anywhere e.g at the beginning of the line, between letters, at the end etc.  As mentioned both conditions MUST be met, this means that minimum is 1 of each to be present in the file.

Comment: Can you combine the last two greps with `grep -E " [a-z]|[a-z] "` ?

Comment: Hi, this seems to work. What if I want to change the '[a-z]' to [:lower:]? As I've read it's better to use this. Is following a good syntax: `egrep '^[[:lower:] ]*$' $DIR/$file | egrep ' ' | egrep '[[:lower:]]' `

Comment: What does the ` t`  is doin there ?

`egrep: t: No such file or directory`

EDIT : ahh its your testfile probably :)

Comment: That was me testing it out on a machine with a file `t` - I would have thought you could have fixed that bit

Comment: I've realized it 1 sec after posting the previous comment :). Your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` may be better to express such conditions:

```
awk '/^[ a-z]+$/ && /[a-z]/ && / /' file
```

That is, it checks that a line:

- consists in just spaces and lowercase letters.
- it contains at least a lowercase.
- it contains at least a space.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello this is something simple
but SUDDENLY not
wah
wa ah
$ awk '/^[ a-z]+$/ && /[a-z]/ && / /' a
hello this is something simple
wa ah
```

Comment: Yeah, this gives the same result as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: The `$0 ~` in each case aren't needed.

Comment: Much more concise now :) I guess the only other thing is that the OP might be interested in using `[:space:]` (or `\s` in GNU awk).

Answer (score 1):

First grep all lines that only consist of lowercase characters and whitespace, and then all those that contain at least one whitespace.

```
egrep -x '[[:lower:][:space:]]+' "$DIR/$file" | egrep '[[:space:]]+'
```

The `[:space:]` meta class also matches for tabs, and can be replaced with a plain space if desired.